# Executable to change default programs

Tags: windows, portable-apps

I have a flash drive with several portable apps on it (Foxit, Chrome, etc.) that I bring to the computer lab at my university. Is there anyway to create an executable that I can run from my drive that will automatically change the system's defaults to open files with the applications on my flash drive?

Comment: If this is a public computer lab and you bring your own portable applications, won't you make yourself unwelcome by modifying default settings?

Comment: The lab computers are probably locked down anyway. If not they should be.

Comment: The computers on enterprise accounts - technically it saves with each individual machine I log into, but I rarely get the same machine twice. I can do it manually (set chrome as default browser, that sort of thing). Just wondering if there's a repeatable process.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the file, choose "Open with..." and select the executable from your flash pen